# Q: How to Update Boolean Value?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I ran into a small issue. I am trying to update Bool value in my Quiz app. If the initial value is true and after a user guessed the question right, I want this value to become false. So far the println("Will be updated to false") does show me the result I want, but I can't figure out the way to update the value in the column "check" in Parse.

```
 var query = PFQuery(className:"Questions")
        query.whereKey("check", equalTo:true)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                // The find succeeded.
                println("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) scores.")
                // Do something with the found objects
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    for object in objects {
                        println(object.objectId)
                    println("Found the true value")
                        if object["check"] as Bool == true  {
                            println("Will be updated to false")

                            }

                        }
                }
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                println("Error: \(error) \(error.userInfo!)")
            }
        }
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you edit the objects, then you save them to parse. Try this:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"Questions")
query.whereKey("check", equalTo:true)
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        // The find succeeded.
        println("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) scores.")
        // Do something with the found objects
        if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {

            // === cache the objects, you want to edit ===
            var tmp = [PFObject]()
            // ===========================================

            for object in objects {
                println(object.objectId)
                println("Found the true value")
                if object["check"] as Bool == true  {
                    println("Will be updated to false")

                    //=== Set the object to false =======
                    object["check"] = false
                    tmp.append(object)
                    //===================================
                }
            }

            // === save all edited objects ===========
            PFObject.saveAllInBackground(tmp, block: {
                (success: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if success == true {
                    println("done")
                }
            })
            // =======================================

        }
    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        println("Error: \(error) \(error.userInfo!)")
    }
}
```